# How were the police manipulated in The Invisible Man?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-invisible-man-2020

In *The Invisible Man* (2020), Cecilia is getting notified that Adrian committed suicide.

Later we find out that Adrian is alive, although he was considered dead.

How did he manipulate the police?

Comment: Did you mean how he could have staged his own suicide scene?

Comment: @YuZhang yes, shouldn't the police investigate it?

Comment: yes, they should. But they apparently reached the wrong conclusion, either they treated it as a suicide without investigating it at all or they did investigate but reached the conclusion that it was a suicide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plot hole.  The brother showed Cecilia a photograph of a body with one arm outside of a sheet.  It's presumed that the body is Adrian's.  However, when she is shown the photo, her friend (who happens to be a police officer) also sees the photo yet makes no inquisition about Adrian's death.  Clearly, that's not how reality works.  So, this is a plot hole which requires [suspension of disbelief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspension_of_disbelief) in order to proceed with the story.  The only explanation is that Adrian's brother took the photo, and Adrian never committed suicide.  I mean, how can you fake a suicide and have it pass by police officers and a coroner, unless they're all part of the cover-up, which they weren't?